# Обработать клик по кнопке в ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть простейшее MVC приложение из кнопки `<button>` и текстового поля `<text>`. Как при клике на кнопку изменить текст в `<text>`?
У меня вот такой контроллер :

```
    public class TableController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
     public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.ListViewTable = ListButtonName.CollectionNames;
        ViewBag.ConcretString = "Empty";
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetName(object sender)
    {
        ViewBag.ConcretString = "!!!";
        return View();
    }
}
```

И сгенерированное `View` :

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <table>
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListViewTable)
        {
            <tr><td><button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("GetName")'" id="@item">@item</button></td></tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <text>@ViewBag.ConcretString</text>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

В ответ возвращается ошибка :

> Не удалось найти данный ресурс.
>
> Запрошенный URL: /Table/GetName

Как правильно реализовать команду в MVC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка происходит из-за атрибута `[HttpPost]` на методе контроллера `GetName`, так как в результате присвоения `location.href= ...` выполняется GET запрос.

```
public class TableController : Controller
{
  [HttpGet]
  public ActionResult Index(string id)
  {
    ViewBag.ListViewTable = ListButtonName.CollectionNames;
    ViewBag.ConcretString = "Empty";
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmoty(id))
      ViewBag.ConcretString = "!!!" + id + "!!!";
    return View();
  }
}

@foreach (string item in ViewBag.ListViewTable)
{
  <tr><td>@Html.ActionLink(item, "Index", new { id = item })</td></tr>
}
```

Comment: Вы не поняли, я хотел что бы метод `Index` осуществлял начальное заполнение страницы а метод `GetName` выполнялся по щелчку на кнопку и добавлял какой то контент к странице разве так нельзя или неправильно ?

Comment: @Сергей я упростил Ваш код. Вы попробовали мой вариант?

Comment: Я не в коем случае не хотел вас задеть или обидеть. На мой взгляд ничего "хамского" я не написал. Очень сожалею если все же так получилось.

Comment: Хотел понять ваш пример прежде чем пробовать. Я хотел понять как работают контроллеры. Как я понимаю, у каждого вью может быть только  один контроллер и в контроллере может быть сколько угодно методов действий которые обрабатывают запросы от пользователя. Таким образом обработка нажатия на кнопку внутри представления должна быть обработана еще одним методом-действия в том же контроллере. Надеюсь я правильно все понял.

Comment: @Сергей Так, давайте по порядку. С ошибкой, которая у Вас была (GET/POST), мы разобрались?

Comment: Да, ошибка действительно исправлена. Только понимания вопроса не прибавилось скорее наоборот.

Comment: @Сергей Атрибут `[HttpPost]` примененный к action-методу контроллера, говорит о том, что этот метод должен отвечать только на запросы с действием (глаголом) POST. Назначение на клиенте `location.href= ...` ведет к запросу страницы с глаголом GET. Поэтому ASP.NET MVC  не нашел подходящего контроллера и метода (ресурса), чтобы ответить на этот запрос.

Comment: Да, это понятно. Мне не понятен сам принцип контроллеров: один контроллер = одно представление так ведь ? Как одна вьюмодель = одно представление в WPF/

Comment: Получается что если я хочу изменить какой то элемент View то мне придется заново вызвать контроллер Index и перестроить всю страницу ?

Comment: И у вас небольшая ошибка. `ActionLink` должен принимать `item` как строку а не `dynamic argument`. Правильнее будет так :`<tr><td>@Html.ActionLink((string)item,"Index", new { id = item})</td></tr>`

Comment: @Сергей Да, я обычно не пишу `foreach(var item ...`; замените это на `foreach(string item ...`, тогда каст не понадобится. В ASP.NET MVC нет жестокого соответствия между action-методами контроллеров и представлениями. Любой метод может вызвать любое представление, указав его имя, - посмотрите параметры перегруженых вариантов метода `View`. Где есть жесткое соответствие - это между представлениями и моделями.

Comment: Получается - любой метод в контроллере может возвращать представление?

Comment: тот, у которого тип возвращаемого значения - `ActionResult`

Comment: те опять же в одном контроллере должен быть только один метод возвращающий `ActionResult ` ?

Comment: нет, таких методов может быть много, и они могут возвращать представления (всей страницы и частичные), текст, JSON, файлы

Comment: тогда не понимаю - если есть много методов которые возвращают View то это же разные View а у одного представления может быть только один контроллер.

Comment: да, но у одного контроллера может быть много View

Comment: вроде начал понимать. спасибо за пояснения!